# Perstisting local data after update from app store

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app for android and ios with Xamarin.Forms where I have to store data, which the user enters.

The data **may never be deleted**, except the user deletes them within the app or by deinstalling the app. But the data must be persisted when the user installs an update via the app store.

Also the data (which is a json string) contains no token or other temporary data. **Every day** the data **could be increase by 200-300 string characters**.

At the moment I use *Application.Current.Properties*, but I'm not sure if it fits both of my requirements...

**Which framework/approach is the best for it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your json string into a file. You'll get it back after an update.

Comment: I would not recommend to use that library as when you migrate to .Net Standard, you might get some trouble